# jQuery and Twitter Bootstrap - Dropdown getting split

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the dropdown feature in my navbar using Twitter Bootstrap and Jquery Mobile. I created a 5-element navbar using jQuery Mobile and referred to the dropdown from Twitter Bootstrap. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get the 5 dropdown elements to drop down. Instead, they split up into 5 parts when It comes to the last column which is to be a dropdown. Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<body>
<div data-role="navbar" data-grid="d" data-iconpos="bottom">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active" data-icon="star">Class</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="star">Activity</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="star">Ratings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-icon="star">Reports</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</body>
```

Comment: Here is a link to the complete page so that you can copy paste it and run without the need to include the stylesheets and js separately. http://pastebin.com/CNRX4zMv

Comment: Perhaps jQuery Mobile navbar styles are overriding Bootstrap's dropdown styles?

Comment: @KhalidT : If I choose one over the other, I will lose some functionality. I prefer jQuery though.

Comment: try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rX35s/), maybe you want this...

Comment: Thanks. Can the solution be done using jQuery Mobile alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Likes this: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rX35s/1/) or on [Full Screen](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rX35s/1/show/)

**CODE:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Website</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active" data-icon="star">Class</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="star">Activity</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="star">Ratings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-icon="star">Reports</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you're new use [this](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) guide

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But I have two issues. One being that the icon's don't work and the other being that while it is responsive on jsfiddle, it is not responsive on mine. 
I will update you on the status after removing all my code and starting from scratch. Shouldn't take long.

Comment: See these [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples), after opening, view their souce _(CTRL + U)_ then compare them with your code, hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks. I see that You have used Bootstrap for this. Can it be done with jQuery Mobile alone?

Comment: Yes, [This](http://jsfiddle.net/nQTTC/) is done by using jQuery Mobile, but require some JavaScript, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aVkgp/) it only use jQuery Mobile. Both examples are same but first use some JS and the other not... For more see [this](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/popup/) and [this](http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/docs/pages/popup/index.html)

Comment: Thank You. It did not exactly solve the problem, but I managed to learn a lot and I thank you for introducing me to the wide range of possibilities.